# Problems with delete, update in Rails 4.2 and backbone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I can not catch the problem. Don't have critical errors. All work fine at other Rails app, with the same config.

```
class PricesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @prices = Price.all

    respond_with @prices
  end

  def show
    respond_with @price
  end

  def update
    @price.update_attributes(price_params)

    respond_with @price
  end

  def create
    @price = Price.create(price_params)

    respond_with @price
  end

  def destroy
    @price.destroy

    respond_with @price
  end

  private

  def price_params
    params.require(:price).permit(:title, :cost)
  end
end
```

When POST all Ok, new price add. But when I try delete or update catch 500 error

```
Started DELETE "/prices/2" for ::1 at 2015-02-10 07:49:24 +0400
Processing by PricesController#destroy as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/prices_controller.rb:26:in `destroy'


Started PUT "/prices/2" for ::1 at 2015-02-10 08:12:23 +0400
Processing by PricesController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2", "title"=>"Price1 update", "cost"=>140, "created_at"=>"2015-02-10T00:04:39.881Z", "updated_at"=>"2015-02-10T00:04:39.881Z", "price"=>{"id"=>"2", "title"=>"Price1 update", "cost"=>140, "created_at"=>"2015-02-10T00:04:39.881Z", "updated_at"=>"2015-02-10T00:04:39.881Z"}}
Unpermitted parameters: id, created_at, updated_at
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/prices_controller.rb:14:in `update'
```

Perhaps it is a problem with jquery-ujs? Because create are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're initializing `@price`, which is why you're getting the error. Try:

```
def destroy
  @price = Price.find(params[:id])
  @price.destroy
  ...
end
```

You'll also need to initialize `@price` in your `show` and `update` actions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the errors, ruby is telling you precisely what the problem is:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/prices_controller.rb:26:in `destroy'
```

So, line 26 is `@price.destroy` so the error is telling you that there's no method `destroy` for `nil`, ie. it's telling you that `@price` is `nil`, ie. it's unset.  Same with `update` except there it's `update_attributes` that is being called on a nil object.

Hopefully that's all you need to see the problem here, ie. you're not setting `@price` in your `destroy` or `update` actions, also not in your `show` action btw.

Comment: Thank you, but it's work at another app. In codeschool  [anatomy of backbone](https://github.com/codeschool-courses/anatomyofbackbone/blob/master/app/controllers/todos_controller.rb)  they are not define a variables in controller.

Comment: Ouch, you diss my answer and then accept someone else's who said the same thing. That stings man ;)  The app you linked to **does** define the variables, look at the `before_filter`.